# Defining a Custom Mask for Visual Basic.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a text box that takes Postal Code inputs (its not just alternating letter and numbers). The postal code needs to follow this regular expression:

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$
```

I've been trying to get a regular expression (regex) equivalent for VB.Net Custom Mask, but it seems you can't do more than just alternate letters and numbers.

So far if I would follow the custom mask "encoding", it would be : `>L0L0L0`
Which only restricts the user for the alternate Letter-Number-Letter-Number-Letter-Number input.

If you look closely to the above regular expression, you can clearly see that not all letter-number variations are valid. Certain letters are not even used.

Now, I could validate this by coding it or validate with the database but I'm wondering if there's not something I'm missing.

Is there a way to encode `>L0L0L0` so that it matches my regular expression ?

[image]

I'm currently using VB.Net on Visual Studio 17 Community version.

Comment: It looks like there are no quantifiers available. That's a problem regarding `.*`. Maybe `>L0L#0L0` but that would allow two digits in the middle.

Comment: No, it is usually not possible, you need to enforce an on-submit (on-input, whatever you call it) regex check.

Comment: This is not possible with masking. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/using-regular-expressions-with-the-maskedtextbox-control) on the only symbols available for use.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I guess there is no way around this one!